# How to modify the same method in a set of sibling classes?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, pyqt, super

I have two classes (Table and Button) inherited from the same class Widget. Both subclasses have their own keyEvent() methods and both call Widget.keyEvent() when necessary. I want to modify the keyEvent() behaviour for both classes in the same way (for example make `A` and `D` keys to trigger `LEFT` and `RIGHT` keys).

This code works exactly as I want

```py
class KeyModifier:
    def keyEvent():
        # some lines of code
        super().keyEvent()

class MyTable(KeyModifier,Table):
    pass

class MyButton(KeyModifier,Button):
    pass
```

But Pylance is angry because KeyModifier.super() doesn't have any keyEvent() method (which is true).

Is there a way to do it better? Also, I would like Pylance to warn me when using the KeyModifier with something not inherited from Widget.

This example comes from a PyQT app, but the question is more general.

Edit:
Making KeyModifier a subclasss of Widget makes KeyModifier.super().keyEvent() call Widget.keyEvent() and I want to call the child class method (Table.keyEvent() or Button.keyEvent())

Comment: Why not make `KeyModifier` inherit from `Widget`? It will have `keyEvent` then

Comment: Because then KeyModifier.super().keyEvent() calls Widget.keyEvent() and I want to call Table.keyEvent() (or Button.keyEvent())

Comment: In that case add `super().keyEvent()` to `MyTable` and `MyButton` as well

Comment: @JordiTorrents this doesn't really make sense from an inheritance perspective, unless you add new intermediate class. A class decorator miight be a better solution. Either that or have `MyTable` and `MyButton` define a *different* method which `KeyModifier` can then call with the updated contract. This way the contracts / constraints of the methods is much clearer.

Comment: Fix for pylance: `super().keyEvent() # type: ignore`.

Comment: Don't put absolute trust in syntax checking **warnings** (warnings are **not** errors). What you're doing makes perfectly sense and has absolutely nothing wrong. Pylance *complains* because it doesn't know the whole context of the program.

Answer (score 1):

Does it help?

```
from abc import abstractmethod


class Table:
    pass


class Button:
    pass


class KeyModifier:
    @abstractmethod
    def custom_operation(self):
        pass

    def key_event(self, condition):
        if condition:
            self.custom_operation()


class MyTable(KeyModifier, Table):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyTable, self).__init__()

    def custom_operation(self):
        pass


class MyButton(KeyModifier, Button):
    def custom_operation(self):
        pass
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you make `KeyModifier` inherit from `Widget`, the warning will be gone because `keyEvent` will actually be defined for the object. If you also add `super().keyEvent()` calls to your modified classes, all the proper events will fire thanks to something called MRO - Method Resolution Order.

```
class Base:
    def event(self):
        print("Base")

class A(Base):
    def event(self):
        print("A")

class B(Base):
    def event(self):
        print("B")

class Modifier(Base):
    def event(self):
        print("Modified")
        super().event()

class ModifiedA(Modifier, A):
    def event(self):
        print("ModifiedA")
        super().event()

class ModifiedB(Modifier, B):
    def event(self):
        print("ModifiedB")
        super().event()

ModifiedA().event()
```

Output:

```
ModifiedA
Modified
A
```

It is important to note that if `A` and `B` do not call a super on their own (I'm fairly certain that PyQt widgets DO call their parent though), `Modifier` has to be the first class inherited, as it will cause it to be first in MRO and have a chance to call the other class method in turn.

Comment: This could be a great solution but it brings a new problem. PyQt6 cannot deal with ModifiedA saying `TypeError: could not convert 'ModifiedA' to 'A'` whenever I try to call some A method. This happens only when Modifier is inherited from Base. This seems to be more like a PyQt problem and the fact that all these classes are, in fact, wrapers around C++

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround as I don't really have to manage any class methods but the event that is being handled.

```
def KeyModifier(event: Event) -> Event:
    # some lines of code and edit 'event' if necessary
    return event

class MyButton(Button):
    def keyEvent(self, event: Event):
        super().keyEvent(KeyModifier(event))
```

I think this is the simplest way to write it. Thank you all for your suggestions :)